# Preserve width of box plot in ggplot when varying number of boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to preserve the width of boxplots in ggplot? By default, the width will vary depending on how many boxes that are included in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about manually setting x axis?

```
# Problem: different widths between these two plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl<8,], aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

# Solution: fix x axis
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl<8,], aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('4', '6', '8'))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p1, p3, ncol=2, main='Before', sub='After')
```

[image]